# Smooth affine variety as a symplectic resolutions

Tags: resolution-of-singularities, stratifications, symplectic-resolutions

Given a smooth affine variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$ with an algebraic symplectic form $\omega$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $X$ by symplectomorphisms, then

1. Is it true that $X$ is trivially a symplectic singularity in the sense of Definition 2.1 in Kaledin's paper [Symplectic singularities from the Poisson point of view](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310186)?
2. Is it true that the canonical projection $X\to X/G$ is a symplectic resolution of the symplectic singularity $X/G$?
3. If $X$ is trivially a symplectic singularity, are the connected components of the isotropy types $X_H$, $H\leq G$, a stratification satisfying the hypothesis in Theorem 2.3 in [Kaledin's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310186)? In particular, does the product decomposition (2.1) hold true?

Comment: I wouldn't say $X$ is a symplectic singularity but it certainly has symplectic singularities by that definition.

Comment: I made a mistake. I meant to write "symplectic variety", not "symplectic singularity". So, you confirm that $X$ is a symplectic variety, right? It is obvious to me, too. But since there is no symplectic resolution of $X$ other than $X$  itself (if we are allowed to do that), I was wondering if I don't want too much.

Comment: You are certainly allowed to take a variety to be a resolution of itself. I don't think $X \to X/G$ is a symplectic resolution because it is not a resolution since it is (usually) not birational.

Comment: This is a very good point! Thank you. What about the orbit type strata $X_H^i$ which are  simply the connected components of the isotropy types? We know that they define a canonical stratification of $X$. But are they the canonical stratification in Kaledin's theorem $2.3$?